# How does Ubuntu handle multiple drives?

Tags: drivers, hard-drive, storage

I have two drives on this laptop. C: and D:. I am afraid that if I switch I will only have the one I installed Ubuntu on. I plan on erasing windows and using Ubuntu as my main OS. So, if anyone could help me. How does Ubuntu handle having multiple drives.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why don't you use Ubuntu installation media to "Try Ubuntu" before installing?  FYI: there's no such thing as "C" and "D" in Ubuntu. That's just how Windows labels volumes/partitions.

Comment: @Nmath oh ok. I will.

Comment: If you need more help with this, you should also tell us if you actually have two hard drives or if they are partitions on the same disk and tell us what file system each one uses and what they contain.  You should always keep good backups at a different location because altering partitions and modifying installed systems has the potential to cause data loss especially if you're not really sure what you're doing.

Comment: @Nmath they are separate drives. One is a SSD and the other is a HDD. The SSD is usually for my OS and i use the HDD for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C: and D: drives in Windows are in fact not actual disks, they are **partitions**, or you may call them logical disks. These partitions may be located on **two separate physical disks** or they may be **two partitions on a single physical disk**. So the first thing to know is how many **actual physical disks** you have inside your laptop - one or two? (**Edit**: I see from the comments that you have two physical drives actually, so I adjusted the rest of the answer for that case.)

Linux does not use such names as C: or D:. It uses names like `/dev/sda` for the first disk and `/dev/sda1` for the **first partition on first disk**. But you normally use these names only in very specific situations, like system installation, because during normal system use, the partitions are **mounted** and appear as one common filesystem not being divided between multiple "drives". For example, `/home` folder may be physically located on the partition you call D: in Windows, and everything else except the `/home` folder may be located on the partition you call C: in Windows (it depends on how you installed the system), but you don't see any difference when you normally browse through folders' contents.

If you install Ubuntu using default installation, it will use only **one physical disk**, create a single partition on that disk and put everything there. So if you plan to remove Windows and install only Ubuntu, the only thing is to make sure that it installs on the disk that is currently your disk C:. If this is the first disk (`/dev/sda`), then Ubuntu should choose it for installation automatically.

However, your second disk (Windows D:) will not be **mounted** in the system with this type of installation, so Linux will not use it directly. However, you should see this unmounted drive icon when browsing your computer contents, and if you double-click on it, it should be mounted automatically and you will be able to use it.

However, this is a bit inconvenient as your second drive will be mounted in some strange location like `/media/username/F6065D30065CF35B`. If you want to have it in a more convenient location, like eg. `/data`, you can use custom installation mode.

In this mode you manage partitions on disk yourself and tell the installer exactly what partition Ubuntu should use for what purpose. So, if `/dev/sda1` is your Windows partition, you tell the installer to **format** it (delete the contents), and mount that partition on **the root file system**, named just `/`. This is where your Ubuntu system will be installed. Your other partition is `/dev/sdb1` and you tell the installer to **not** format it and mount it for example on `/data` folder.

Of course you need to understand well what is on what partition if you plan to use custom installation mode. When you boot up your computer from a live version of Ubuntu, you can find an application called **GParted**. This is a partition editor that lets you view what disks and what partitions are there in the computer. You can also optionally delete and/or create partition with it, if it will be needed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119026/discussion-on-answer-by-raj-how-does-ubuntu-handle-multiple-drives).